# Python - Crossplatform filepath

Tags: python, filepath

normally I'm using a mac for my scripts, but now I'm facing a problem on Windows.

Is there a good way to make paths ready for cross platform ?

```
def load_json(store):
    storename = store
    
    with open('./stores/' + store +'.json' ,'r') as store:
        data = store.read()
    
    object = json.loads(data)
```

On Windows im getting the error

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './stores/alternate.json'
```

Comment: `os.path.join('.', 'stores', store + '.json')`

Comment: `join()` won't help if you leave the slashes in the strings.

Comment: Windows is perfectly happy to accept forward slashes everywhere, except in the command line.  Evidently, that file is not where you think it should be.

Comment: When I run python from the command line it works, but when I run it from VS Code it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way:

Edited the launch.json File from VS Code on Windows and added:

`"cwd": "${fileDirname}"`

Now VS Code is starting in the right Directory and not in D:\GitHub